# Obtain the total number of samples with FFMpeg

Tags: c++, c, audio, ffmpeg

Currently my application reads audio files based on a while-realloc loop:

```
// Pseudocode
float data* = nullptr;
int size = 0;
AVFrame* frame;
while(readFrame(formatContext, frame))
{
    data = realloc(data, size + frame.nSamples);
    size += frame.nSamples;
    /* Read frame samples into data */
}
```

Is there a way to obtain the total number of samples in a stream at the beginning? I want to be able to create the array with `new[]` instead of `malloc`.

Comment: Note, you could use a `vector`.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, this was answered here:
[FFmpeg: How to estimate number of samples in audio stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32015306/ffmpeg-how-to-estimate-number-of-samples-in-audio-stream)

I used the following in my code:

```
int total_samples = (int) ((format_context->duration / (float) AV_TIME_BASE) * SAMPLE_RATE * NUMBER_CHANNELS);
```

NOTE: my testing shows this calculation will be most likely be more than the actual number of samples found, so make sure you compensate for that in your code.  I set all remaining "unset" samples to zero.